# How to make all the random strings be different? [Python]

Tags: python, random

I'm starting to write a program that make all the letters from the alphabet be transformed in symbols and "codified".

```
import random

char = ("@", "#", "$", "%", "&", "*", "-", "¿", "=", "?", "~", "§", "!", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "£", "º", "°")

a = random.choice(char)
b = random.choice(char)
c = random.choice(char)
d = random.choice(char)
e = random.choice(char)
f = random.choice(char)
g = random.choice(char)
h = random.choice(char)
i = random.choice(char)
j = random.choice(char)
k = random.choice(char)
l = random.choice(char)
m = random.choice(char)
n = random.choice(char)
o = random.choice(char)
p = random.choice(char)
q = random.choice(char)
r = random.choice(char)
s = random.choice(char)
t = random.choice(char)
u = random.choice(char)
v = random.choice(char)
w = random.choice(char)
x = random.choice(char)
y = random.choice(char)
z = random.choice(char)

print a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z
```

How can I make every single letter have it's own symbol and not repeat?
Some output I got:

```
°10?¿012=~===7251@&=2784£-

°¿~°°?¿£%!2~$270!5º%5@0*1º

~6@&~0£!896~!7?$0-£8461-¿-
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `random.shuffle()` and don't assign to 26 separate variables:

```
import random

char = list(u"@#$%&*-¿=?~§!1234567890£º°")
random.shuffle(char)

print(u''.join(char))
```

Here `char` is a (randomly shuffled) list, where the indices could be used instead of using separate variables. So `a` is found at index `0` in the list.

I made the characters a list of *Unicode* codepoints, since you are using non-ASCII characters here.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.10

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 6, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: @shm: right, that's because we can't just reshuffle UTF-8 bytes. I've made it a Unicode string instead, you are using non-ASCII characters, after all.